# How to cache a custom block on each product in the category view?

Tags: cache

I would like to add caching for a block on a per product basis.

I tried just adding:

```
protected function _construct()
{
    //cache for half a day
    $this->setCacheLifetime(43200);
}
```

The problem is a single cache entry is used for every product.
So if I load the first page with products that has specific html in it. Then on all other products the same html is shown.

So it is caching the entire block using a default block tag.

How would I cache the block for the page/url as well as per product?

Update:

`$this->getProduct()->getId()` to the `getCacheKeyInfo()` function I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getId() on null
```

**Update: Add Block Code**

```
class Module_Sticker_Block_Badge extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        //cache the stickers for half a day
        $this->setCacheLifetime(43200);

        // Add cache tags
        // cache tags are used as handles for clearing certain caches
        $this->setCacheTag(array(
            Mage_Core_Model_Store::CACHE_TAG,
            Mage_Cms_Model_Block::CACHE_TAG,
            Tengisa_Sticker_Model_Sticker::CACHE_TAG
        ));
    }

    // Cache key is unique per bit of HTML
    public function getCacheKeyInfo()
    {
        return array(
            Module_Sticker_Model_Sticker::CACHE_TAG,
            $this->getNameInLayout(),
            Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(),
            Mage::getDesign()->getPackageName(),
            Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('template'),
            //Product id
            // $this->getParentBlock()->getProduct()->getId()
            // Mage::registry('product')->getId()
            $this->getProduct()->getId()
        );
    }
```

Comment: Are you currently using an FPC/Varnish or particularly interested in the block caching layer? Also what version of Magento are you using? I would take a look at pricing blocks on category pages to help understand how it is implemented.  Also AOE_TemplateHints https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_TemplateHints will show you cache details of each block, even color coding states.

Comment: I am only using standard magento caching. Aha I'll take a look at the pricing blocks.

Comment: I will suggest you to follow up the article explained by alanstorm - http://alanstorm.com/magento_listener_lifecycle_block
You will get you answer if you follow it carefully

Comment: @rajatsaurastri The issue is accessing product from the block. I am not seeing a reference to that in the article.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `$this->getProduct()->getId()` to the `getCacheKeyInfo()` function I
>   get the following error:
>
> ```
> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getId() on null
> ```

Adding the product ID to `getCacheKeyInfo()` is the right thing to do. But it looks like at least in some cases your block does not have the product available with `getProduct()`. Make sure that `getProduct()` is implemented and actually returns a product instance.

---

> How would I cache the block for the page/url as well as per product?

You were talking about category pages, so I assume there are multiple *different* instances of your block on one page. In this case I don't see sense in using the URL for the cache key.

On product pages you could use `Mage::registry('current_product')` to refer the current product and on category pages, the same with "current_category".

I cannot tell, if any of these make sense to you. If you need more concrete help, please update the question with relevant code of your custom block.

---

### Update based on comment

> I just use setData to set the data I need in the template: `<?php echo
>   $this->getChild('badge')->setData('stickers',
>   $_product->getStickers())->toHtml(); ?>` and then access in the
>   template with: `$this->getStickers()`

In this case, the block has no access to the product id. Now you have two possible ways to solve it:

1. use the stickers data for the cache key

   ```
   \md5($this->getData('stickers')
   ```
2. additionally pass the product id

   ```
   $this->getChild('badge')->setData('product_id', $_product->getId());
   ```

   and then use it for the cache key

   ```
   $this->getData('product_id')
   ```

Note that you pass generated HTML (`product->getStickers()->toHtml()`) from outside, so it is generated every time even if the block itself is cached.

To optimize this, you should move this HTML generation **into** the block so that is is only executed if the block is not already cached.

The parent template then should look like this:

```
$this->getChild('badge')->setData('product', $_product);
```

The additional data for the cache key:

```
$this->getData('product')->getId()
```

And the blocks `_beforeToHtml()` method (which is only called if the block was not cached):

```
protected function _beforeToHtml()
{
     parent::_beforeToHtml();
     $this->setData('stickers', $this->getData('product')->getStickers()->toHtml());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added my current block code. Please check and see if there are any red flags.

Comment: I don't see anything product related. How do you access the product in the template?

Comment: I am doing it incorrectly. I tried using `$this->getParent()->getProduct()->getId()` but that also gave a `null` on `getProduct`. The parent class is `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`

Comment: Oh, I just use `setData` to set the data I need in the template: `<?php echo $this->getChild('badge')->setData('stickers', $_product->getStickers())->toHtml(); ?>` and then access in the template with:  ` $this->getStickers()`

Comment: I see. Please see my update

Comment: I'm not too sure why you need the `_beforeHtml()`

Comment: Optimization. To only execute this code if the block is not loaded from cache.

Comment: I thought it does that automatically. The whole blocks content has already been cached. When it has not been cached the `setData` will already have been called from the template

Comment: So this was the template of the block itself? I thought it was from the *parent* block. If I misunderstood that, you are right and it is not necessary to change (but best practice nonetheless)

Answer (score 0):

1. after instance this block, setProduct($product)(block extends
   Varien_Object)
2. setCacheKey(),please ensure its unique(ex. MY_BLOCK_NAME . $product--getId());or, you can rewrite the function
   'getCacheKeyInfo()'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for but to cache custom block and then clean cache exactly for this block I use the next approach which works good to me:

1. Implement \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface and set your custom cache tag like

   ```
   use Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface;
   use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
   use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
   ...

   class Block extends Template implements IdentityInterface
   {
       public const CACHE_TAG = 'custom_cache_tag';

       public function __construct (
           ...
           Context $context,
           array $data = []
       ) {
           parent::__construct($context, $data);
           ...
       }

       public function getIdentities(): array
       {
           return [self::CACHE_TAG];
       }

       ...

   }
   ```
2. Use it to clean cache in a place you need

   ```
   use Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface;
   use Magento\PageCache\Model\Cache\Type;

   ...

   public function __construct (
       ...
       private readonly CacheInterface $cache,
       private readonly Type $fullPageCache
   ) {
   }

   public function cleanBlockCache (): void
   {
       $tags = [Block::CACHE_TAG]; //tag from our custom block
       $this->cache->clean($tags);
       $this->fullPageCache->clean(\Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_MATCHING_ANY_TAG,$tags);
   }
   ```